# Remainder Theorem application

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, limits

The remainder theorem of elementary algebra states that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $r$ is all real, then there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$

$$P(x)=Q(x)(x-r)+P(r)$$

a. Show that $$\lim_{x\to r} Q(x) = P '(r)$$

My Work-
I have to prove this using variables but, I first tried seeing how it works with numbers work.

$$P(x)=x^3+2s^2-4x+5$$

$$Q(x)=(x^2+4x+4)$$

$$r=2$$

$$\lim_{x \to 2} (x^2+4x+4) =16$$

$$\frac{dP}{dx}= 3x^2+4x-4       $$

$$\frac{dyP(2)}{dx}=16$$

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It's immediate using the standard definition of the derivative. Are you using some nonstandard definition?

Comment: The Leibniz definition for the derivative is precisely, the ratio of rise versus run is the slope of the curve.

Comment: I'm trying to the statement up there is true using variables instead of numbers. I don't know how I should start.

Comment: What is your definition of the derivative of the polynomial $P\,$? Is it not the same expression you obtain above by solving for $Q$ then substituting that value of $Q$ into the limit? Normally they *are* the same. Or maybe you were stuck on algebra or doing that solving and substitution?

Comment: srry I typed that part wrong, and I don't know how to use Mathjax, so it came out weird. Its supposed to be as x approaches r the limit of Q(x) = P'(r)

Comment: @Donutmunch You just forgot to put the closing $$ at the end of your limit expression. You should just edit to put them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just using the usual limit definition of the derivative? If so you can just write:

$$Q(x) = \frac{P(x)-P(r)}{x-r}$$
$$\lim_{x\to r} Q(x) = \lim_{x\to r} \frac{P(x)-P(r)}{x-r} = P'(r)$$

(as everyone in the comments already pointed out).

Comment: To still resolve the confusion, the derivative is taken at $x = r$

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän thanks, edited.